# spring cloud sleuth not working with apache camel(2.22.2) with spring boot(2.3.12) application

Tags: apache-camel

I could see in the logs it's not generating trace id and span id when we hit any camel route please guide how to reslove the problem.The required jars on class path but still unable to see trace id and span id in the logs not sure exactly what was missing please help in reslove the probelm
Thanks in advance